# Windows form from console

Tags: c#, console, winforms

I would like to spawn a Windows form from the console using C#. Roughly like `display` does in Linux, and modify its contents, etc. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to add a reference for System.Windows.Forms and then be good to go.  You may also have to apply the STAThreadAttribute to the entry point of your application.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }
}
```

... more complex ...

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var frm = new Form();
        frm.Name = "Hello";
        var lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = "Hello World!!!";
        frm.Controls.Add(lb);
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can initialize a form in the Console. Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms and use the following sample code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form f = new System.Windows.Forms.Form(); 
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Can I get some comments on the downmods?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It may not be great practice, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: +1 because it works without the STAThread attribute. Maybe it could potentially have other issues without the attribute, but that does not make it deserving of any down-votes. If there's a problem, better to mention it in a comment and let the poster fix it.

Comment: This page (and others) recommends you either use the STAThread attribute, or create the form in a separate thread and manually set the AppartmentState:  http://blogs.msdn.com/jfoscoding/archive/2005/04/07/406341.aspx

Comment: He got the downvotes before he extended his answer.  But it would still be nice if people would say why instead of just down voting.

Comment: What is the opinion on posting half answers? I've seen Marc do it several times, so I figured it was normal.

Answer (score 4):

The common answer:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{    
   Application.Run(new MyForm());
}
```

Alternatives (taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jfoscoding/archive/2005/04/07/406341.aspx)) if, for example - you want to launch a form from a thread other than that of the main application:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartNewStaThread)); 

// Make sure to set the apartment state BEFORE starting the thread. 
t.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA; 
t.Start(); 

private void StartNewStaThread() { 
    Application.Run(new Form1()); 
}
```

.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartNewStaThread)); 
t.Start();

[STAThread]
private void StartNewStaThread() { 
    Application.Run(new Form1()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new MyForm()); 
}
```

Bye.